# Select middle rows in sql

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, datagrid

I have a table in my SQLServer database with almost 100K records in it and a web application in which I want to show a paged gridView presentation of these rows. Clearly I should filter the rows and return a small subset of them to client(because of the Ajax performance on web).

Here's my main problem. What's the best approach to select the middle rows? For example How can I select the rows from #50000 to #50010? Is there a way like `select top 10` or `select bottom 10` that selects the rows from middle of the table rows.

I'm using linq2sql in a .NET MVC web application & also can code SQL StoredProcedures.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Linq2Sql` this is not that hard. You can use:

```
dataContext.GetTable()
    .Skip(50000)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

[Scott Guthrie has a post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx) on this matter, which has some more explanation. And `Linq2Sql` will actually produce sql using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Some small hint, the order of your expressions is important:

- `.Where()`
- `.Select()`
- `.OrderBy()`
- `.Skip()`
- `.Take()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's Great to do it using linq.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure abt this, but anyway

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY colm) RowNumr, colm FROM table) t
WHERE RowNumr BETWEEN 50000 AND 50010
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. I tried your code and it's Perfect. but I should prefer the linq approach. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Check this link out, you can use the rownumber to get the rows you need based on a sort order.  Just add a where clause where the rownumber is between the your paging limits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from(select table_name.*,rownum as rn from table_name order by column desc) table_name
where rn between 5000 and 5010;
```